# Azure logic apps standard calling local function error

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

With the recent enhancement in logic apps standard we have the ability to call a .NET custom code that is wrapped in a function with "Call local function" action.

This is all working fine in VS code when testing locally but getting the below error when deployed to azure. Just to mention here, i only deployed logic app standard to workflow service plan WS1 but did not deploy function as i think functions dll is already part of the logic app artefacts. All the demos and articles on web only talk about VS CODE but not deployment to azure

> Error: GetFunctionFailed The function"xxxxx" does not exists in the function app

Do we need to deploy both logic app and function app for this to work?

I have deployed logic app with WS plan and not ASEV3 plan so is that an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have referred this [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-run-custom-code-functions) to create custom code function in logic app standard.

Once the workspace is created, compile your code by executing below code in function terminal,

```
dotnet restore
dotnet build
```

Ensure, you have functions dll created in `lib\custom`.

[image]

I have deployed my logic app like below

[image]

[image]

[image]

Even I have created my logic app in WS1 service plan.
After deployment, I can see my logic app workflow.

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks and really appreciate your reply..I have tried again and still getting the same error. Few things to clarify here 1. I have used logic app project with extension bundle and not nuget based so did you use the same or did you test with nuget based project? 2. For this in azure logic app app setting I have FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME set to "node". so is it same with your project as well? Thanks

Comment: Yes even I have used extension and for me also it is set to `node`

Comment: yep..it worked out now on my personal laptop..may be it is an issue with corporate network hence marking the question as answered. Thanks